# ヒープ汚染を警告抑制以外で解決する方法

Tags: java, android-studio, ヒープ, android-asynctask

ヒープ汚染の改善方法に困っています。`@SafeVararges` のような警告抑制ではなく、どの様に解決出来るのか分かりません どなたか教えてください。

```java
public static class　Hiep extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Bitmap>, Bitmap, String> {

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<Bitmap>... params) {
```